# Trouble with prophecy and PHP DOM

Tags: php, phpunit, prophecy

I've been moving my PHPUnit tests to use PHPSpec's Prophecy library - but I'm getting an odd error when using dummies of PHP DOMDocument:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function testExample() {
        $inputDocument  = $this->prophesize("DOMDocument")->reveal();
        $outputDocument = $this->prophesize("DOMDocument")->reveal();

        $xsltProcessor = $this->prophesize("XSLTProcessor");
        $xsltProcessor->transformToDoc($inputDocument)->willReturn($outputDocument)->shouldBeCalled();
        $xsltProcessor = $xsltProcessor->reveal();

        $xsltProcessor->transformToDoc($inputDocument);
    }
}
```

I get an error `ErrorException: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input`

I'm not sure why loadXML is being called - these are supposed to be dummies...

Comment: Can you share the SUS class please?

Comment: I don't know what SUS means?

Comment: The class you are testing.

Comment: DOMDocument and XSLTProcessor are PHP built-ins - the code above is all you need (along with the PHPUnit library) to replicate the issue - I wrote this test case as is to make sure it wasn't any of my own code causing the problem. Also - I still don't know what SUS means...

Comment: You can find the definition here: http://everzet.com/post/33178339051/sus-collaborators

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this message not because of Prophecy (it works very well), but (surprise) because of `vendor/sebastian/comparator/src/DOMNodeComparator.php` on line 84

Use this `phpunit.xml` file to see what I mean:

```
<phpunit
    convertErrorsToExceptions="false">
</phpunit>
```

The error pops up when phpunit is trying to get a textual representation of a DomDocument. Thus, the call to loadXML().